# Partial matrix transformation

Tags: matrix, transform

If I have a 3x3 matrix that represents either a 2d rotation, translation or scale (or some combination of those) is there a way of multiplying it with either a constant, or another matrix to compute a partial transformation matrix.

For example, if I knew the matrix was a translation matrix I could simply multiply `m[0][2]` and `m[1][2]` by some constant (e.g., 0.25) to create a 1/4 (of m) translation matrix.

Is there a generic approach that will work regardless of the matrix? If not, is there a separate approach that will work for each of the types listed (rotation and scale).

Answer (score 1):

This is just homologous to [OpenGL 3D transformations](https://open.gl/transformations). So Yes, just omit the *z* row/column and you can represent 2D translation, rotations and scale with 3x3 matrices products.

For instance:

Translations:

```
|1  0  Tx| |x|   | x+Tx | 
|0  1  Ty|*|y| = | y+Ty |
|0  0  1 | |1|   |  1   |
```

Rotations:

```
|cos(w) -sin(w) 0| |x|   | x*cos(w)-y*sin(w) |
|sin(w)  cos(w) 0|*|y| = | x*sin(w)+y*cos(w) |
|  0     0      1| |1|   |         1         |
```

Scale:

```
|Sx 0  0| |x|   | Sx*x |
|0  Sy 0|*|y| = | Sy*y |
|0  0  1| |1|   |   1  |
```

In case you want to combine more transformations it's possible to apply more of them. Say you have a scale operation, **S** and a translation, **T**.

now given a vector **v0** you can scale it: **v1**=**S** * **v0**

Than you can translate it:

**v2**=**T** * **v1**

that is:

**v2**=**T** * **S** * **v0**

**T** * **S** is the composite transformation that

1. scale the vector
2. translate it

Let's think now to what is the transformation performed in opposite order: **S** * **T**

1. translate the vector
2. scale it

note that the scaling now will scale also the translated coordinates - differently from the first case.

Now you are asking of an operation that transforms the operation, not the vector. I would try with this: obtain a vector **v3**:

1. perform the inverted scale operation
2. translate the inverted scaled vector
3. scale it

These will result in the vector at the original scale, translated of the "scaled translation". This is commonly written as:

**v3** = **S<sup>-1</sup>** * **T** * **S** * **v**

where **S<sup>-1</sup>** is the *inverse matrix* (**S<sup>-1</sup>** * **S** = **I**, identity matrix) that performs the opposite operation.

**S<sup>-1</sup>** * **T** * **S** is the transformation you are looking for. The approach is very general.

Comment: I'm not sure you read the question, i'm know how to perform the transformations, I'm not sure how to take a matrix that represents a certain transformation, and make it move 1/4 or 1/10th of the distance

Comment: I think the edits explain how a translation can be scaled down, but translation is easy to scale in any case, the more difficult one to scale is the rotation

Comment: "scaling a rotation"? Please explain - the approach is very general for operators and matrices, rotations included. You can "scale after a rotation" or before of it. But "scaling a rotation" - that has determinant equal to 1 by definition is an odd concept.